# orbit slider not working on a mobile device

Tags: zurb-foundation, orbit

I am using the orbit slider module for a project.

It works great when I view it by reducing the browser size, but does not work at all on a smaller device.

I am using zurb foundation theme for the responsive frame work which is actually pretty good.

Here is the link to the site

http://nycplatformdev.devcloud.acquia-sites.com/

Comment: This post was edited to use a secure URL instead of the one you initially had. If this was an invalid edit, please revert the change. Both pages look the same, so it would probably be better to use the one you initially had since it doesn't have an invalid SSL certificate.

Comment: I thought I did remove the ssl. Apparently I did not. But thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your main div was set to twelve columns. You could set that to include smaller columns for smaller resolutions if I'm not mistaken.

```
 <div class="small-4 large-12 columns">
```

But then again, you didn't specify what foundation version the theme was created in nor what CMS the theme is for. It could be anything from the stylesheet to the foundation.js you're including to activate the orbit plugin. Please include all information and set something up in Fiddle if you can that shows the actual markup along with the foundation version.

More information = better answers.

Comment: Hey there I used the Drupal theme
https://drupal.org/project/zurb-foundation

And I am using this contributed module
https://drupal.org/project/field_orbit

I will try to create a fiddle to recreate the problem. Working on it

Comment: Ahh, looks like you are using Foundation 3. The markup I supplied is for Foundation 4 (the latest version).